# Separating alternating lines of a text file into two different but corresponding arrays C++

Tags: c++

Ok, so I have been trying to figure this out for a couple hours and have literally gotten nowhere. None of the answers to similar questions I found make any sense to me. I assume because we haven't gotten that far into the curriculum yet.

I need to take an input text file formatted with responses and categories like so,

```
Yes
positive
Maybe
vague
No
negative
```

and put it into two different arrays (responses[], categories[]). I have to use a function to do this. My instructor gave us the function declarations but not definitions so for this we have,

```
void readResponses(ifstream &infile, string responses[], string categories[], int &size)
```

I can open a file and put it into an array no problem. I know how to use the array and print it out, etc. I just don't know how to separate the two. Is there a way to use getline and put every other line into an array? Sorry if this is a repetitive question but thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be stuck in a particular mode of thinking, based on how you normally read lines.  A common way to read a text file is one line at a time in a loop as follows:

```
void foo(std::istream& inStream)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inStream, line))
    {
        // Do stuff with line
    }
}
```

Now, if you're expecting that every input is two lines of text, just read two lines at a time:

```
void foo(std::istream& inStream)
{
    std::string response, category;
    while (std::getline(inStream, response) && std::getline(inStream, category))
    {
        // Do stuff with response and category
    }
}
```